# Extracting the largest rectangle like object from an image with any possible orientation using openCV?

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I have pictures of cheques which were scanned and are on A4 sheets now.
I need to extract those cheques, which can be a bit tilted or rotated.
Now using an AI model would be my last preference. I tried the following script and it gave away every little and tiny rectangle from the image

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from google.colab.patches import cv2_imshow

# Read the image into a NumPy array
image = cv2.imread('/content/img.jpg')

# Convert the image to grayscale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Use the Canny edge detector to find the edges of the objects in the image
edges = cv2.Canny(gray, 50, 150)

# Find the contours of the objects
contours, _ = cv2.findContours(edges, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

# Iterate through the contours
for contour in contours:
  # Approximate the shape of the contour as a polygon
  epsilon = 0.1 * cv2.arcLength(contour, True)
  approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(contour, epsilon, True)

  # If the approximated polygon has 4 sides, it is a rectangle
  if len(approx) == 4:
    # Extract the rectangle from the image
    x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(contour)
    rectangle = image[y:y+h, x:x+w]

    # Do something with the rectangle (e.g., display it, save it to a file, etc.)
    cv2_imshow(rectangle)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

and this is what my images look like
what would be the best non YoLo type of solution here

[image]

Comment: What's your required output? Can't you just filter by rectangle area? What's the next step in the pipeline and the specifications of what you're trying to obtain?

Comment: the whole cheque 
that's all i need @ShlomiF

Comment: cv2_imshow("Image", rectangle)

Comment: @toyotaSupra yes, in google colab thats how you do it. you cant use cv2.imshow() there, as it'd crash the colab notebook

Comment: Sorry. I didn't see namespace.